# How to create dripping Spray can tool for Graffiti app in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to create a spray can tool in Android for a Graffiti app. I want to achieve something similar done in the below image

[Dripping Spray Can Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNGm2.jpg)

Requirements: If somebody is spraying the can then it should drip some color downwards while drawing a spray line

I am currently using the following code, but not getting the correct results:

```
if (bufferPaint == null) {
        bufferPaint = new Paint();
        bufferPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        bufferPaint.setDither(true);
        bufferPaint.setXfermode(null);
        if (mPaint == null)
            setupColor(0f, 100f);
    }
    int alpha = Math.round((float) 100 / 100 * 255);
    bufferPaint.setAlpha(alpha);


private void paintOneDab(float x, float y) {
        float radius = 5 / 2f;

        float scatter = 500 / 100f;
        x += radius  2  scatter  (1 - 2  (float) Math.random());
        y += radius  2  scatter  (1 - 2  (float) Math.random());
        float hardness = 20 / 100f;
        positions[0] = 0;
        positions[1] = (float) (Math.sqrt(hardness));
        positions[2] = 1;
        bufferPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(x, y, radius, colors, positions, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));


        mCanvas.save();

        int angle = 180;
        mCanvas.rotate(angle, x, y);

        int roundness = 100;
        mCanvas.scale(1f, 100f / roundness, x, y);

        mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, bufferPaint);

        mCanvas.restore();
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, I have edited the title. I need one tool for the Graffiti app which can drip some drops when I am spraying it. Please check the attached image in question